# .bind() that does not return native code in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using a library that uses .bind() to change the context of an object it's sending to a second library. The second library needs to use .toString() to parse the object.  And because .bind() returns a function with [native code], the whole project is broken. I'd like to create a function `simpleBind(fn, context)` that sets the context of `fn` to `context` but returns a function that `.toString()` still works on.

```
var different_context = {foo: 4}   
function a_fun () {return this.foo}
a_fun() // undefined
a_fun.toString() // 'function a_fun() {return this.foo}'
a_fun.bind(different_context).toString() // 'function bound a_fun() { [native code] }'
a_fun.bind(different_context)() // 4
```

Ideally, the `simpleBind` function would work like:

```
var boundFunction = simpleBind(a_fun, different_context);
boundFunction() // 4
boundFunction.toString() // 'function a_fun() {return this.foo}'
```

I've read a bunch of things about how contexts work in js, and about what the .bind() function does, but I haven't been able to figure this out. Is this just impossible for some reason?

#### Edit

I realized the question's not quite complete.  The library that wants to parse the bound function expects a string that looks like `"function [function_name] ([function_arguments]) {[the code is not important]}"`.  So I'm trying to bind the function while still producing a string with that structure.

Comment: The MDN documentation has a [pure JS implementation of bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill)

Comment: Erp. That's embarassing. Thanks!  Didn't see that.  But unfortunately, it doesn't work... or rather, it does work as `bind()`, but the library that's trying to parse the function assumes the function's name and arguments will be in a certain place in the string, and the string that the MDN implementation returns does not look like a regular 'function a_fun {return this.foo}'.  I'll edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Why does the library do that? That's a terrible API. Rather then messing around with the string representation you should look what the library does with the extracted data.

Answer (score 3):

I found this quite interesting. My solution is a bit of a hack, but seems to work:

```
function simpleBind(fun, ctx){
    var newFun = function(){
        return fun.apply(ctx, arguments);
    }
    newFun.toString = function(){
        return fun.toString();
    }
    return newFun;
}
```

Passes your tests

It works by wrapping the old function in a new one, passing a new context on execution. Then it replaces the `toString` implementation on the new function to call the `toString` of the original function.

Comment: Please explain _how_ your implementation ensures the `toString()`-requirement. :)

Comment: Excellent. Very clever. Thanks!